# Primefaces Spinner how avoid to show Zero?

Tags: primefaces, spinner

Hi i am using Primefaces Spinner Component [Primefaces Spinner](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/spinner.jsf)

I will want to show empty Spinner nothing inside Spinner as by default it is showing zero. Can we avoid this? Can we show empty Spinner?

Comment: I would try changing integer to string and give empty or space to spinner

Comment: Hmm then we have to parse that String ..not a bad idea

Comment: Try binding it to an `Integer`, that should default to null. Hopefully the component can autounbox it

Comment: The wrapper classes, allowing `null`, work. But once something has been entered, is there a way to remove this value again, setting the backing property to `null` again? It seems, this is not possible?

Comment: At what point of time you will want to empty the fields? I have clear button which performing this task. What scenario you want to add?

Comment: @subodh let's say I have a field "Maximum length" (Integer) which is unknown at the beginning of a process (=null). Some time later, I fill in some value but later this turns out to be wrong. So I want to remove that value from the field again, setting it back to `null`. Any chance to achieve that?

Comment: If i am able to understand your question then you have to add clear button in which you will call a action method of managed bean which have the logic to do it null.

Comment: OK, thanks, I will try that for at least the most important fields ... ;-)

Comment: Just for reference so this can be found via Google: I prototyped the Javascript for the spinner and replaced the logic how a value is prefilled: `PrimeFaces.widget.Spinner.prototype.initValue = function() {
 var a = this.input.val();
 if (a == "") {
  if (this.cfg.min != undefined && this.cfg.min > 0) {
   this.value = this.cfg.min;
  } else {
   this.value = 0;
  }
...`

Answer (score 2):

I fixed above issue to make changes in in my bean class used Wrapper classes Integer,Float rather than int,float.